# Change the parent size to the average of his children's size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I do something like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663 
But  in this exemple, parent's size are the sum of there children's size, I would like that the  parent's size will be the average of there children's size. But i didn't know which part of code should be edited to have the wanted result. Can you help me please. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to modify the underlying data (readme.json) for that.

Comment: But readme.json contains only children's size, the function that calculate the parent's size is in the index.html. they are deducated from the children's size

Comment: Ah, right. Well this example uses the partition layout, which always sums up the values -- this is not configurable. You would need to modify the source to do averages.

Comment: :( how can i modify the source ?

Comment: Clone the repository on github and code away.