# function to calculate the averages of children's size D3 js

Tags: d3.js

Hi I'm doing something like this
 http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663

But in this exemple, parent's size are the sum of there children's
size, I would like that the parent's size will be the average of there
children's size. So i need to Implement a function to calculate the averages as I wish -- function average(d) in my example -- and replace all occurrences of

```
            .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
```

with

```
           .attr("width", function(d) { return x(average(d)); }).
```

But i don't know how to implement it . Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really asking basically the same question again for the *third* time? Didn't I already tell you that you need to modify the source to do this?

Comment: I tried to change this .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); }) with another function that i implement it ,and it worked. So surely if i find how to implement a function that calculate the average, it will work too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the parent size to the average of his children's size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482798/change-the-parent-size-to-the-average-of-his-childrens-size)

Comment: Recursively count the number of children for each node and store it in the property data. Then simply divide the sum of the children by the number of children

Comment: yes,I tried with this function function average(d) {
         if (d.children !=null)
   {console.log(d3.sum(d.children, function(d) {return d.value;})/d.children.length); return d3.sum(d.children, function(d) {return d.value;})/d.children.length;}
  
  else{
  return d.value;
  }
 
} then I replace all occurence of .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); }) with .attr("width", function(d) { return x(average(d)); }) But it calculate the average only for the lastest parents and their children. Have you any idea how can I correct this function to calculate the average for all parents ?