# function to calculate the parent size from children's size

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm doing something like this, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663
But I want that the parent's size was the average of children's size. I found a solution, but It works only for the last parent. My proposition is to implement a new function average

```
                   function average(d) {
if (d.children !=null){

return d3.sum(d.children, function(d) {return d.value;})/d.children.length;}

                else{
            return d.value;
                }

                  }
```

Then  I replace all occurence of

```
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
```

with

```
             .attr("width", function(d) { return x(average(d)); })
```

But it calculate the average only for the lastest parents and their children. Have you any idea how can I correct this function to calculate the average for all parents ?
It's the third time i asked this question, but please understand me, it's very interesting for me, and I know that i will find solution if someone helps me 
Thanks a lot

Comment: make a fiddle with your data, then we could do something on it....

Comment: But isn't d.value already the sum of the children? So you would just need to return d.value/d.children.length; Or how does your data look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [function to calculate the averages of children's size D3 js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499957/function-to-calculate-the-averages-of-childrens-size-d3-js)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to invent a new function to find the average of a certain property for each element in an array of objects. You can use [`d3.mean`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_mean) for that.

You could just use a recursive function to add a new property to each node that has children, calling it something like `averageChildValue`.

For example, you could do this:

```
function recurse(node) {
  // IF A NODE HAS CHILDREN...
  if (node.children) {
    // ADD A PROPERTY REPRESENTING THE AVG VALUE OF ITS CHILDREN
    node.averageChildValue = d3.mean(node.children, function(d) { 
      return d.value;
    });
    // RECURSIVELY CALL THE FUNCTION ON THE CHILDREN
    node.children.forEach(function(d) { recurse(d); });
  }
}

d3.json("readme.json", function(error, root) {
  // PARTITION THE DATA
  partition.nodes(root);
  // USE THE RECURSIVE FUNCTION TO CALCULATE THE AVERAGES
  recurse(root)
  // DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR NEW-AND-IMPROVED DATA
  console.log(root)
});
```

Check your console output and each node with children should now have an extra property called `averageChildValue`.

Comment: and should i replace  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })    with    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(recurse(d)); })   ?

Comment: No, the method I suggested would alter your entire dataset, so if you wanted the width to be a function of the avg size of the children, you would base the width attribute on that value directly such as: `.attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.averageChildValue); })`

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( showing in the console : Valeur NaN inattendue lors de l'analyse de l'attribut width.